# this would make us look like cheats vs this would make us looking like cheats

Tags: infinitives

> this would make us look like cheats

vs

> this would make us looking like cheats

which is the right one, and why?

Comment: Please see also: [ell.se] Good Luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"This would make us look like cheats." is correct; the reason is that "This would make us look" is in the future tense, as a hypothetical result of some action, and "looking" is a present-tense or active verb.

Comment: Hi Eve. 
I can understand that "This would make us look" is in the future tense, but i can't understand the use of the ing-form as a present-tense or active verb. I mean, I thought that, in some circumstances, the ing-form could be used in future constructions.

Comment: 'This would make us look like cheats', 'This would cause us to look like cheats', and 'This would leave us looking like thieves' all speak of future results following from a given course of action or occurrence, but all have different catenation patterns.